# How to re-encode a video file's audio, but leave the video stream with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding

Does anyone know how to take a video and re-encode the audio, but just copy the video data using FFMPEG?

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible to do with `ffmpeg` with one command, but more information is needed for an exact example. What audio format do you want for the output? Please show some information about your input: `ffmpeg -i input.foo`

Comment: Another forgotten question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Apparently FFMPEG can do this, I had to use `-c:v copy` and that will leave the video stream intact. I actually used an app called iFFMPEG to figure this out.

Comment: Note that if your input contains more than one video stream then only one will be [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) by default. You can add `-map 0:v` to include all video streams or simply `-map 0` to include all streams regardless of type (video, audio, subtitle, data, etc). See the documentation on [stream selection](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I know that [Virtual Dub](http://www.virtualdub.org) can do this, but it only works with a limited number of codecs. Since it's free, it's worth a look to see if it'll do what you want.

Otherwise, any demux/remux software will work, but it'll take three steps. First demultiplex the file into video and audio streams, re-encode the audio as needed, then remux them into a combined stream.